# Pandas - How to groupby, calculate difference between first and last row, calculate max, and select the corresponding group in original frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns I am interested in: A categorical label and a timestamp. Presumably what I'm trying to do would also work with ordered numerical data. The dataframe is already sorted by timestamps in ascending order. I want to find out which label spans the longest time-window and select only the values associated with it in the original dataframe.

I have tried grouping the df by label, calculating the difference and selecting the maximum (longest time-window) successfully, however I'm having trouble finding an expression to select the corresponding values in the original df using this information.

Consider this example with numerical values:

```
d = {'cat': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
     'val': [1,3,5,6,8,9,0,5,10,20,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Here I would expect something equivalent to `df.loc[df.cat == 'B']` since B has the maximum difference of all the categories.

```
df.groupby('cat').val.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()).max()
```

gives me the correct difference, but I have no idea how to use this to select the correct category in the original df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the category that gave rise to maximum peak-to-peak value within groups ([`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) does the maximum minus minimum). Then you can index with `loc` as you said, or [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
>>> max_cat = df.groupby("cat").val.apply(np.ptp).idxmax()
>>> max_cat
"B"

>>> df.query("cat == @max_cat")  # or df.loc[df.cat == max_cat]

  cat  val
6   B    0
7   B    5
8   B   10
9   B   20
```